# Is the global request timeout broken in 16.0.0?

Tags: advanced-rest-client

I’ve set the global request timeout under Preferences (Mac) to 10 seconds. I’ve also made sure that per-request configuration is disabled for my request. However, ARC seems to wait indefinitely for a response seemingly disregarding the 10 second timeout I set. Is there something I’m missing or is this basic functionality indeed broken?

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in this version of the app and it is now fixed in 16.0.1.